# OpenAI Integrating custom game into a gym environment

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

[**Introduction**] I'm a beginner with OpenAI, I have made a custom game into which I would like to implement a self-learning agent. I followed [this guide](https://github.com/openai/gym/tree/master/gym/envs) to set up a repository on GitHub, however I do not understand how I could format my code to work with the contents of gym-foo/gym_foo/envs/foo_env.py

[**Question**] Is there any chance someone could guide me on how to structure my code to so it’s compatible with:

```
class FooEnv(gym.Env):
metadata = {'render.modes': ['human']}

def __init__(self):
  ...
def step(self, action):
  ...
def reset(self):
...
def render(self, mode='human', close=False):
  ...
```

[**Code**]

```
import pygame
import time
import random
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

display_width = 1002
display_height = 720

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
red = (220,0,0)
blue = (53,155,255)
green = (0,190,0)
bright_red = (255,0,0)
bright_green = (0,255,0)
dark_blue = (0,102,204)
yellow = (255, 255, 0)

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height)) #creates surface/ display
pygame.display.set_caption('Blob Arena') #name of project
clock = pygame.time.Clock() #sets a clock

#________________________________________________________________________________________

blobImage = pygame.image.load('blob2.png')
blobIcon = pygame.image.load('blob_img.png')
bulletpicture = pygame.image.load("bullet.png")
pygame.display.set_icon(blobIcon)
pause = True
blob_width = 51
blob_height = 51
bullet_width = 12
bullet_height = 5

bullets=[]
bullets2=[]

def blob(x,y):
    gameDisplay.blit(blobImage,(x,y)) #drawing to background

def bullets_hit(count):
    font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 25)
    text = font.render("Score: "+str(count), True, black)
    gameDisplay.blit(text,(0,20))

def player_lives(count):
    font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 25)
    text = font.render("Lives Left: "+str(count), True, bright_red)
    gameDisplay.blit(text,(0,0))

def game_intro():
    intro = True
    while intro:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        gameDisplay.fill(dark_blue)
        largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 110)
        TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("Blob Arena", largeText)  # Returns text surface and rectangle
        TextRect.center = ((display_width / 2), (display_height / 2.5))
        gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)
        button("Training 1", 200, 430, 140, 53, green, bright_green, game_loop)
        button("Training 2", 431, 430, 140, 53, green, bright_green, game_loop)
        button("Training 3", 662, 430, 140, 53, green, bright_green, game_loop)
        button("Human vs AI", 315.5, 550, 140, 53, green, bright_green, game_loop)
        button("Quit", 546.5, 550, 140, 53, red, bright_red, quit_game)

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15)

def button(msg,x,y,w,h,ic,ac,action=None):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed() #collects mouse left, right and middle button
    if x + w > mouse[0] > x and y + h > mouse[1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, ac, (x, y, w, h))
        if click[0] == 1 and action!= None:
            action()
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, ic, (x, y, w, h))

    smallText = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf", 20)
    textSurf, textRect = text_objects(msg, smallText)
    textRect.center = ((x + (w / 2)), (y + (h / 2)))
    gameDisplay.blit(textSurf, textRect)

def unpause():
    global pause
    pause = False

def paused():
    largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 110)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("Paused", largeText)  # Returns text surface and rectangle
    TextRect.center = ((display_width / 2), (display_height / 2.5))
    gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

    while pause:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        button("Continue", 315.5, 450, 140, 53, green, bright_green, unpause)
        button("Quit", 546.5, 450, 140, 53, red, bright_red, quit_game)

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15)

def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, black)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

def quit_game():
    pygame.quit()
    quit()

def game_over():
    largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 110)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("Game Over", largeText)  # Returns text surface and rectangle
    TextRect.center = ((display_width / 2), (display_height / 2.5))
    gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        button("Play Again", 280.5, 450, 140, 53, green, bright_green,game_loop)
        button("Quit", 581.5, 450, 140, 53, red, bright_red,quit_game)

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15)

def game_loop():
    global pause
    x = (display_width * 0.08)
    y = (display_height * 0.2)

    x_change = 0
    y_change = 0

    blob_speed = 2

    velocity = [2, 2]

    score = 0
    lives = 3

    pos_x = display_width/1.2
    pos_y = display_height/1.2

    previous_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    previous_time2 = pygame.time.get_ticks()

    gameExit = False
    while not gameExit:
        for event in pygame.event.get():#monitors hardware movement/ clicks
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        pos_x += velocity[0]
        pos_y += velocity[1]

        if pos_x + blob_width > display_width or pos_x < 601:
            velocity[0] = -velocity[0]

        if pos_y + blob_height > display_height or pos_y < 0:
            velocity[1] = -velocity[1]

        for b in range(len(bullets2)):
            bullets2[b][0] -= 6

        for bullet in bullets2:
            if bullet[0] < 0:
                bullets2.remove(bullet)


        current_time2 = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        #ready to fire when 500 ms have passed.
        if current_time2 - previous_time2 > 500:
            previous_time2 = current_time2
            bullets2.append([pos_x+25, pos_y+24])

# Checks to see if any keys are held down and remembers them with the variable keys.
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        for b in range(len(bullets)):
            bullets[b][0] += 6

        for bullet in bullets:
            if bullet[0] > 1005:
                bullets.remove(bullet)

        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
            #ready to fire when 500 ms have passed.
            if current_time - previous_time > 500:
                previous_time = current_time
                bullets.append([x+25, y+24])

# If the player is holding down one key or the other the blob moves in that direction
        if x < 0:
            x = 0
        if keys[pygame.K_a]:
            x_change = -blob_speed
        if x > 401 - blob_width:
            x = 401 - blob_width
        if keys[pygame.K_d]:
            x_change = blob_speed
        if keys[pygame.K_p]:
            pause = True
            paused()


# If the player is holding down both or neither of the keys the blob stops
        if keys[pygame.K_a] and keys[pygame.K_d]:
            x_change = 0
        if not keys[pygame.K_a] and not keys[pygame.K_d]:
            x_change = 0

        if y < 0:
            y = 0
        if keys[pygame.K_w]:
            y_change = -blob_speed
        if y > display_height - blob_height:
            y = display_height - blob_height
        if keys[pygame.K_s]:
            y_change = blob_speed


        if keys[pygame.K_w] and keys[pygame.K_s]:
            y_change = 0
        if not keys[pygame.K_w] and not keys[pygame.K_s]:
            y_change = 0


        #print(event)
        # Reset x and y to new position
        x += x_change
        y += y_change

        gameDisplay.fill(blue)  #changes background surface
        bullets_hit(score)
        player_lives(lives)
        pygame.draw.line(gameDisplay, black, (601, display_height), (601, 0), 3)
        pygame.draw.line(gameDisplay, black, (401, display_height), (401, 0), 3)
        blob(pos_x, pos_y)
        blob(x, y)

        for bullet in bullets:
            gameDisplay.blit(bulletpicture, pygame.Rect(bullet[0], bullet[1], 0, 0))
            if bullet[0] > pos_x and bullet[0] < pos_x + blob_width:
                if bullet[1] > pos_y and bullet[1] < pos_y + blob_height or bullet[1] + bullet_height > pos_y and bullet[1] + bullet_height < pos_y + blob_height:
                    bullets.remove(bullet)
                    score+=1

        for bullet in bullets2:
            gameDisplay.blit(bulletpicture, pygame.Rect(bullet[0], bullet[1], 0, 0))
            if bullet[0] + bullet_width < x + blob_width and bullet[0] > x:
                if bullet[1] > y and bullet[1] < y + blob_height or bullet[1] + bullet_height > y and bullet[1] + bullet_height < y + blob_height:
                    bullets2.remove(bullet)
                    lives-=1

        if lives == 0:
            game_over()


        pygame.display.update() #update screen
        clock.tick(120)#moves frame on (fps in parameters)

game_intro()
game_loop()
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

[**Additional Information**] I will be using a reinforcement learning algorithm from https://github.com/Hvass-Labs/TensorFlow-Tutorials/blob/master/reinforcement_learning.py which from my understanding requires a gym environment in order for gym.make() to work. Any help would greatly be appreciated, if anything more is needed please tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no experience with the `pygame` library and no knowledge of its internal workings, that may have some influence on what code needs to run where, so I'm not 100% sure on all of that. But, it's good to just start with some intuitive understanding of roughly what should be happening where:

- `__init__()` should run any one-time setup. I can imagine something like `pygame.init()` may have to go in here, but this I'm not 100% sure on because I'm not familiar with `pygame`.
- `step()` should be called whenever an agent selects an action, and then run a single ''frame'' of the game, move it forwards given the action selected by the agent. Alternatively, if you have a game where a single action takes multiple frames, you should run multiple frames here. Essentially: keep the game moving forwards until you hit a point where the agent should get to choose a new action again, then return the current game state.
- `reset()` should... well, reset the game. So, revert back to the (or a random, whatever you want) initial game state, run any cleanup that may be required. I could, for example, also imagine `pygame.init()` belonging in here. It depends on what exactly that function does. If it only needs to be run once, it belongs in `__init__()`. If it needs to run at the start of every new game/"episode", ir belongs in `reset()`.
- `render()` should probably contain most of your graphics related code. You can try to take inspiration from, for example, the [cartpole environment](https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/master/gym/envs/classic_control/cartpole.py) in gym, which also draws some rather simple graphics here. It looks like it should draw exactly one frame.

---

Now, looking at the code you're starting from, there seems to be a signifant amount of User Interface code... all kinds of code related to buttons, pausing/unpausing, a fancy (animated?) intro at the start of the game. I don't know if you can afford to get rid of all this? If you're doing purely Reinforcement Learning, you probably can. If you still need user interaction, you probably can't, and then things become a whole lot more difficult since all these things do not nicely fit the `gym` framework.

I can try to make a few educated guesses of a few of the remaining parts of the code and where it should go, but you should carefully inspect everything anyway based on the more general guidelines above:

```
def reset(self):
    # all the following code seems to define the initial game state
    x = (display_width * 0.08)
    y = (display_height * 0.2)

    x_change = 0
    y_change = 0

    blob_speed = 2

    velocity = [2, 2]

    score = 0
    lives = 3

    pos_x = display_width/1.2
    pos_y = display_height/1.2

    bullets=[]
    bullets2=[]
```

`step()` should probably contain most of the code in that `while` loop in `game_loop()`. The key-input-checking code should be modified though, that should instead start making use of the `action` passed into `step()`. Finally, `step()` is expected to return a tuple containing:

- next game state, something the agent can use to decide what the next action will be. This can be raw pixels if you like, or something that's easier to learn from (like a bunch of features telling you where things are).
- A reward, some indication of how good your agen't action was.
- `True` if the game is over now, `False` otherwise.
- Some dictionary with whatever extra info you like, for debugging purposes. Can simply be an empty dict `{}`.

Comment: Wow! Thank you for the detailed explanation, made it a lot easier to understand. How could I check if I'm making any errors while writing it? For example would running the module after I make the step() method give me an indication of anything I've done wrong inside the step() method or does the whole environment need to be set up in order to start checking for errors?

Comment: @Rokas98765 Hmm that's difficult. There's noone other than you who'll know whether or not code will be ''correct'' once written, certainly nothing inside `gym` itself that could check. A custom environment is precisely that: custom, it can be basically anything you want. The most important thing is to get an intuitive understanding of what the different functions are supposed to do. Then you can try putting `print()`s here and there, see if what you expect to happen happens. If you can get visualization running, that'll obviously help too, then you can look at the screen to see whats happening

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time, was a huge help.

Comment: @Rokas98765 Since the answer has been helpful, kindly accept it - answers take up valuable time for respondents, especially *such* answers...

Comment: @desertnaut my bad, thank you for the reminder.

Comment: Sorry for asking again, I wanted to clarify what is the purpose of metadata? A lot of examples I look at have metadata = {'render.modes': []} and things like 'human' or 'rgb_array' are added inside. I tried searching it up but couldn't find an explanation.

Comment: @Rokas98765 what metadata? Do you mean the last return value of `step()`? That's not guaranteed to contain anything across all environments, so you're free to just return an empty dict. Some environments will put useful debugging info in there, but there's no guarantee that all environments will. You'll see that most RL algorithms simply don't use the return value at all (for example, the RL code you linked to, saves it in the `info` variable in [this line](https://github.com/Hvass-Labs/TensorFlow-Tutorials/blob/master/reinforcement_learning.py#L1774) but doesnt use it at all.

Comment: I should have included an example, when a class is created the first thing set up is metadata, for example [here](https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/master/gym/envs/classic_control/continuous_mountain_car.py) or on another stackoverflow question asking how to [Create new environments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45068568/is-it-possible-to-create-a-new-gym-environment-in-openai/47132897#47132897). So the {} in the return of step() accesses those metadata?

Comment: In the examples I've looked at, the 'human' is taken as an argument in def _render(self, mode='human', close=False) and 'rgb_array' is in the return of that method. Not sure what the use of that is though.

Comment: @Rokas98765 Ah, that metadata. There seems to be a little bit of documentation on it here: https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/78c416ef7bc829ce55b404b6604641ba0cf47d10/gym/core.py#L73

Comment: Can't believe I missed that when looking over it, thanks!