# How can I register a custom environment in OpenAI's gym?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I have created a custom environment, as per the OpenAI Gym framework; containing `step`, `reset`, `action`, and `reward` functions. I aim to run OpenAI baselines on this custom environment. But prior to this, the environment has to be registered on OpenAI gym. I would like to know how the custom environment could be registered on OpenAI gym? Also, Should I be modifying the OpenAI baseline codes to incorporate this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You do not need to modify *baselines* repo.

Here is a minimal example. Say you have `myenv.py`, with all the needed functions (`step`, `reset`, ...). The name of the class environment is `MyEnv`, and you want to add it to the `classic_control` folder. You have to

- Place `myenv.py` file in `gym/gym/envs/classic_control`
- Add to `__init__.py` (located in the same folder)

  `from gym.envs.classic_control.myenv import MyEnv`
- Register the environment in `gym/gym/envs/__init__.py` by adding

  ```
  gym.envs.register(
       id='MyEnv-v0',
       entry_point='gym.envs.classic_control:MyEnv',
       max_episode_steps=1000,
  )
  ```

At registration, you can also add `reward_threshold` and `kwargs` (if your class takes some arguments).
You can also directly register the environment in the script you will run (TRPO, PPO, or whatever) instead of doing it in `gym/gym/envs/__init__.py`.

**EDIT**

This is a minimal example to create the [LQR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear%E2%80%93quadratic_regulator) environment.

Save the code below in `lqr_env.py` and place it in the *classic_control* folder of gym.

```
import gym
from gym import spaces
from gym.utils import seeding
import numpy as np

class LqrEnv(gym.Env):

    def __init__(self, size, init_state, state_bound):
        self.init_state = init_state
        self.size = size 
        self.action_space = spaces.Box(low=-state_bound, high=state_bound, shape=(size,))
        self.observation_space = spaces.Box(low=-state_bound, high=state_bound, shape=(size,))
        self._seed()

    def _seed(self, seed=None):
        self.np_random, seed = seeding.np_random(seed)
        return [seed]

    def _step(self,u):
        costs = np.sum(u**2) + np.sum(self.state**2)
        self.state = np.clip(self.state + u, self.observation_space.low, self.observation_space.high)
        return self._get_obs(), -costs, False, {}

    def _reset(self):
        high = self.init_state*np.ones((self.size,))
        self.state = self.np_random.uniform(low=-high, high=high)
        self.last_u = None
        return self._get_obs()

    def _get_obs(self):
        return self.state
```

Add `from gym.envs.classic_control.lqr_env import LqrEnv` to `__init__.py` (also in *classic_control*).

In your script, when you create the environment, do

```
gym.envs.register(
     id='Lqr-v0',
     entry_point='gym.envs.classic_control:LqrEnv',
     max_episode_steps=150,
     kwargs={'size' : 1, 'init_state' : 10., 'state_bound' : np.inf},
)
env = gym.make('Lqr-v0')
```

Comment: do you have a tip or example on how to register the environment in the script ((TRPO, PPO, or whatever) instead of doing it in )...

Comment: Im trying to follow all of the steps above but I get an error, `gym.error.Error: Attempted to look up malformed environment ID: b'hvac_Env'. (Currently all IDs must be of the form ^(?:[\w:-]+\/)?([\w:.-]+)-v(\d+)$.)`

Comment: @HenryHub I never had your error. I have added a minimal example, hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for Sharing this @Simon... It worked. The LQR seems quite interesting too, would you ever be able to share some contact info to collaborate? Else I can give you mine.. I am attempting to use this custom Gym env for controlling valve in a piping system to a temperature sensor. I have contact info at the bottom of this blog post about my side project:https://medium.com/getting-reinforcement-learning-into-the-bas

Comment: Is this still the way to go in 2020? This seems to be a very awkward practice, since one usually does not want to alter files under package management (pip / conda).

Comment: Ok, I see, this problem has been solved in a clean way already in 2017: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47132897/579698

Comment: Is there any way to do this without modifying the gym package? it seems like you should be able to do so

Answer (score 3):

Environment registration process can be found [here](https://github.com/openai/gym/tree/master/gym/envs#how-to-create-new-environments-for-gym).

Please go through [this](https://github.com/openai/gym-soccer) example custom environment if you have any more issues.

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45068568/is-it-possible-to-create-a-new-gym-environment-in-openai) stackoverflow issue for further information.

Answer (score 0):

That problem is related to versions of gym try upgrading your gym environment.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).