# Register OpenAI Gym malformed environment failure

Tags: python, pip, openai-gym

On a Linux PC, I am attempting to create a custom open AI Gym environment. I can get through all of [the steps from a blog write up from medium.com](https://medium.com/@apoddar573/making-your-own-custom-environment-in-gym-c3b65ff8cdaa) including the `pip install -e .` but I get an error with the final product making the environment `env = gym.make('BASoperator-v1.0')`

The medium blog states this file directory is needed, my naming convention is this:

```
vavBox/
  README.md
  setup.py
  vavBox/
    __init__.py
    envs/
      __init__.py
      vavBox.py
```

This is my setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='vavBox',
      version='0.0.1',
      install_requires=['gym']
)
```

First init.py:

```
from gym.envs.registration import register

register(
    id='vavBox',
    entry_point='vavBox.envs:vavBox',
)
```

2nd init.py in the `env` folder:

```
from vavBox.envs.vavBox import vavBox
```

The `pip install` went fine. I can see that pip installed the 3rd party package. But, when I attempt to import the environment thru this script below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import time
import gym
import vavBox


env = gym.make('vavBox')
```

I get an error, `gym.error.Error: Attempted to register malformed environment ID: vavBox. (Currently all IDs must be of the form ^(?:[\w:-]+\/)?([\w:.-]+)-v(\d+)$.)`

Comment: Follow the [EDIT on this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52727233/registering-a-custom-environment-in-openai-gym/52739974?noredirect=1#comment94167744_52739974) that goes thru the classic_control method...

Answer (score 5):

In vavBox/**init**.py the id should read:

```
from gym.envs.registration import register

register(
    id='vavBox-v0',
    entry_point='vavBox.envs:vavBox', )
```

or something with a "-v[0-9]+" after it to match the regex