# How to register and make a openAI gym environment?

Tags: python, openai-api, openai-gym

I have a custom openAi gym environment. I am trying to follow their [documentation](https://gymnasium.farama.org/tutorials/gymnasium_basics/environment_creation/#registering-envs) of `registering` and creating new instances of the environment using `make` but I keep getting different errors. I am not able to grasp the concept of doing these 2 steps. I have followed multiple StackOverflow [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52727233/how-can-i-register-a-custom-environment-in-openais-gym/52739974#52739974) to implement this but my environment is not getting registered and I am not able to create an instance of it.

My current folder structure.

```
environment 
    > rl.py (This has the environment in it)
    > train.py
```

I want to create an instance of my custom environment in `train.py` and implement different algorithms in it. How can I implement this concept of registering and make with what I have right now? And could you please explain the concept of registering and make for creating instances of environments?

Comment: [ask] and [mre]

Comment: What is the error ?