# integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I am attempting to create a Q table following [this blog post](https://gist.github.com/simoninithomas/baafe42d1a665fb297ca669aa2fa6f92#file-q-learning-with-frozenlake-ipynb) that I found on Medium.com. In my [step function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45068568/is-it-possible-to-create-a-new-gym-environment-in-openai) (python class) for creating a custom open AI Gym environment, my action space `self.action_space` would be 3 possible actions and the possible observations would be a values 50 to 150 in increments of 1 `self.observation_space`.

```
    #possible actions from more_heat less heat functions
    self.action_space = np.array([ 0,  1,  2])

    #possible deviation values from temp - setpoint
    self.observation_space = np.arange(50,150,1)
```

The blog post that I am following creates the Q table by this code below which I think is just creating an array of zeros based on the sizes.

```
action_size = env.action_space.n
state_size = env.observation_space.n

qtable = np.zeros((state_size, action_size))
print(qtable)
```

But when I attempt to print the Q table, I get this error:
`TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index`

Any words from the wise on what I am doing wrong would be greatly appreciated!

Same error just running this code:

```
import numpy as np
action_space = np.array([0,1,2])
observation_space = np.arange(50,150,1)

action_size = action_space
state_size = observation_space

qtable = np.zeros((state_size, action_size))
print(qtable)
```

Comment: Use `env.observation_space.shape[0]` to get the state space. Same for the action space.

Comment: Cool... What does that do? It worked can you help me understand? If you post the answer I can hit the green check box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `env.observation_space.shape[0]` to get the state space size. Same for the action space.

In the blog post you linked, they solve [the frozen lake task](https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/master/gym/envs/toy_text/frozen_lake.py). The task inherits from [the `discrete` class](https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/master/gym/envs/toy_text/discrete.py) which defines the action and obs spaces like this

```
    self.action_space = spaces.Discrete(self.nA)
```

Their [`Discrete`](https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/master/gym/spaces/discrete.py) class has an attribue `n` specifing the size of the discrete space.
Instead, you use [`np.array`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.array.html#numpy.array) which does not. You should actually get an error when you try to do

```
    action_size = env.action_space.n
```

or at least, I do if I try to run your code.

Comment: Hello @simon, Could possibly give me a tip with this SO post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53712923/python-binning-data-openai-gym