# python binning data openAI gym

Tags: python, numpy, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I am attempting to create a custom environment for reinforcement learning with openAI gym. I need to represent all possible values that the environment will see in a variable called `observation_space`. There are 3 possible actions for the agent to use called `action_space`

To be more specific the `observation_space` is a temperature sensor which will see possible ranges from 50 to 150 degrees and I think I can represent all of this by:

EDIT, I had the action_space numpy array wrong

```
import numpy as np
action_space = np.array([ 0,  1,  2])
observation_space = np.arange(50,150,1)
```

Is there a better method that I could use for the `observation_space` where I could bin the data? IE, make 20 bins 50-55, 55-60, 60-65, etc...

I think what I have will work but seems sort of cumbersome... And I am sure there is a better practice as there is not a lot of wisdom on my end this subject. This will print out a Q table:

```
action_size = action_space.shape[0]
state_size = observation_space.shape[0]

qtable = np.zeros((state_size, action_size))
print(qtable)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not really related to programming, so maybe on [stats.stackexchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com) you may get better answers. Anyway, it just depends on how much accuracy you want. I guess you want to change the temperature (increase, decrease, don't change) according to the sensor readings. Is there much different (in terms of optimal action) between 50 and 51? If not, then you can discretize the state space every 2 degrees. And so on.

More generally, doing so you are using what in RL are called "features". A discretization over an interval of the state space is called [tile coding](http://www.incompleteideas.net/book/8/node6.html) and usually works well.

If you are new to RL, I really advise to read [this book](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1opPSz5AZ_kVa1uWOdOiveNiBFiEOHjkG/view), or at least Chapters 1,3,4 which are related to what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks for the response @simon... I will read the book and look into Tile coding.. If I reposted this to stats exchange is the post seem Ok for that site? … Like the way the question is asked as well as the tags etc?? Thanks again..

Comment: You're welcome. The question is a bit too generic, you may want to read more about the topic and then ask for unclear things. For instance you may want to ask when to use specific features, example of algorithms/tasks... And no need for the code and its tags.

Comment: Hi @simon if you don't one more question and my apologize for being sort newb.... Can you tell me what `observation_space = observation_space = np.arange(50,150,1)` actually builds? I get an error that a value of 118 is out of range, so I have just adjusted the  `observation_space = np.arange(0,250,1)`... to hopefully account for this issue. Does the Q table consist of one giant array or matrix, almost like a look up table for an action once training is completed?

Comment: Np, but it is a bit hard to understand your problem. Edit the question with the code and the error, because I don't quite get it (`np.arange(50,150,1)` has 118).