# Custom environments in OpenAI-Gym

Tags: development-environment, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I want to try out reinforcement learning in Python.
But I want to create a custom environment with my own States and Rewards.

Possibly I want to use Time-Series Data in this(nothing like Stocks though).
I want my system to learn behaviors according to time, given an environment.

So I would first start by making a custom environment, 
Can someone help me in that ?

Answer (score 2):

The OpenAI gym environment registration process can be found in the gym docs [here](https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/master/docs/creating-environments.md).

You could also check out [this](https://github.com/openai/gym-soccer) example custom environment and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45068568/is-it-possible-to-create-a-new-gym-environment-in-openai) stackoverflow issue for further information.

> Possibly I want to use Time-Series Data in this(nothing like Stocks though). I want my system to learn behaviors according to time, given an environment.

If you want the agent to learn w.r.t. time then include time-step as a variable in your state. Then your agent will be able to distinguish between two distinct states differ from time-step.