# Implementation of Deep Reinforcement Learning in a Custom Environment

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning

I want a deep reinforcement learning code that implemented by Keras in a custom gym environment. I know that several custom environments have been implemented and introduced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45068568/how-to-create-a-new-gym-environment-in-openai). But, I don't find a complete code implementation of a custom environment beside the deep reinforcement learning model. I just found the predefined environments of the gym beside the deep learning model [here](https://github.com/keras-rl/keras-rl). Has anyone a simple code for this?

Comment: Take a look at stable baselines tutorial for custom environments